# Ninject Web Application: All bindings should be InRequestScope()?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ninject

I have a web application made in asp.net mvc, and i am using Ninject to bind the interfaces.

For now, i have this:

```
// Db Context
kernel.Bind<DbContext>().To<DbEntities>().InRequestScope();

// Repositories - which are using instance of DbEntities
kernel.Bind<ICustomerRepository>().To<CustomerRepository>();
kernel.Bind<IProductRepository>().To<ProductRepository>();

// Services - which are using instances of Repositories
kernel.Bind<ICustomerService>().To<CustomerService>();
kernel.Bind<IProductService>().To<ProductService>();
```

I am binding an DbContext to DbEntities in RequestScope because i want to use the same DbContext in the same web request. After that it should dispose it.

But how the other bindings should be? How they are by default?

For example `IProductRepository` which has an instance of `DbContext` (which is one per request), should also be `InRequestScope()` ?

`IProductService` has an instance of `IProductRepository`

How the bindings should be so is suitable for a web application? (and i don't overload the server's memory)

Comment: Why are you injecting a DbContext? What is your goal with that?

Comment: I want to use the same DataContext instance over the same web request so i can use Transactions for example. If i create a new DataContext inside each Service i have, i can't wrap the methods from different services inside a Transaction

Comment: Injection is not a good way to control object scopes IMO. The purpose of injection is to loosen couplings of objects in your application to ease the scaling, testing and refactoring of your application. However, in this case, isn't really doing so since you are still forced to use a EF DbContext and cannot build a fake repository for testing purposes. You should look at UnitOfWork design pattern to manage your context scope.

Comment: @Pluc You are right about that, but I get confused that EF DbContext already implements UnitOfWork pattern. So i can make an interface IUnitOfWork and make DbContext implement IUnitOfWork and inject it this way

Comment: This is a great question, so the focus should be primarily on the different Ninject scopes that could be used on the repositories and application services, rather than what design patterns should be used for DbContext. This kind of deviates the discussion from the actual point. I was expecting a more fruitful discussion in the comments section, but it is quite unrelated to what the OP has asked!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For MVC application your configuration is ok. There will be no big difference if you bind your repositories in the default transient scope or in the request scope. As @Mark stated in the transient scope your dependencies will be injected as new instances of bounded objects, but in transaction scope they will be created once per request. I prefer little bit more Request scope and recommend it if you want to do (for example) some per-request caching on your repository.

Answer (score 1):

You can leave the repositories as it is. The default scope is such that whenever there is a need of `IProductRepository` a new instance is created.